Forecast using Arima
Please help me: I have problems with the chart is not showing the legend and also the x-axis with the date and has Error in get(".xts_chob", .plotxtsEnv) : object '.xts_chob' not found
enter image description here
# Load necessary libraries
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)

# Fetch historical data
getSymbols("UPM.HE", from = "2004-03-14", to = "2024-05-15", auto.assign = TRUE)

# Extract closing prices
upm_prices <- Cl(UPM.HE)

# Create a time series object
upm_ts <- ts(upm_prices, frequency = 365.25/7)

# Fit ARIMA model
upm_arima <- auto.arima(upm_ts)

# Forecast
upm_forecast <- forecast(upm_arima, h = 62)  # Forecast for 62 days (from March 15th to May 15th)

# Plot forecast
plot(upm_forecast, main = "Forecasted Stock Price of UPM.HE")

# Retrieve actual data for comparison
actual_data <- upm_prices["2024-03-15/2024-05-15"]

# Plot actual data for comparison
lines(actual_data, col = "blue")

# Add legend
legend("topright", legend = c("Forecast", "Actual"), col = c("black", "blue"), lty = 1)

